# c++ (on Clion) for loop stops in the middle with no errors (exit code 0)

Tags: c++, clion

I'm using Clion on windows 10 (with MinGW)

I'm trying to run a very simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        cout << "i is : " << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the loop stops in the middle, with exit code 0.
every running it stops in a different place.
sometimes the last line printed is:

```
i is : 99
```

but sometime, the program ends after printing:

```
i is : 42
```

or even:

```
i is : 67
i is : 6
```

how can i fix it?

thanks

Comment: Happens for me (CLion 2017.2) too randomly, I think it is caused by CLion

Comment: Are you running this program through CLion, or are you running the executable directly? Do both methods produce the same output?

Comment: i'm running it through Clion 2017.3

Comment: Maybe flush the buffer ?

Comment: I have the same problem with CLion 2017.3.3 on Windows 10 using MSVC 2017 (15.0, amd64). IDE's console stops printing at random moment in suchlike loop and reports exit code 0, but executable from cmd works as expected.